# remove groups with sparse observations

Tags: r

suppose I have a data set like this:

```
 df <- data.frame(group = c(rep(1,3),rep(2,2), rep(3,2),rep(4,3),rep(5, 2)), score = c(30, 10, 22, 44, 6, 5, 20, 35, 2, 60, 14,5)) 

      group score
 1      1    30
 2      1    10
 3      1    22
 4      2    44
 5      2     6
 6      3     5
 7      3    20
 8      4    35
 9      4     2
 10     4    60
 11     5    14
 12     5     5
```

...

I want to remove the groups with less than 3 observations, the expected result should like this:

```
      group score
 1      1    30
 2      1    10
 3      1    22
 4      4    35
 5      4     2
 6      4    60
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

@beginneR I like the table approach but I think you can get away without the `merge`:

```
key <- !table(df[, 1]) < 3
df[df[, 1] %in% names(key)[key], ]

##    group score
## 1      1    30
## 2      1    10
## 3      1    22
## 8      4    35
## 9      4     2
## 10     4    60
```

Answer (score 2):

This solution should work just fine. Use `ave` to get the count of values for each `group`

```
df[ ave(df$score,df$group, FUN=length) >=3  ,]

#    group score
# 1      1    30
# 2      1    10
# 3      1    22
# 8      4    35
# 9      4     2
# 10     4    60
```

Comment: even amazing answer!!

Answer (score 0):

Not a very elegant answer but it still works.

My approach is to make a frequency table first by `table()`
Then `merge` the freq table with df and remove those freq less than 3 times.

```
freqtable <- data.frame(table(df$group))
colnames(freqtable) <- c("group","freq")

mergetable <- merge(df, freqtable, by="group")
output <- mergetable[mergetable$freq>=3,][,1:2]
```

And the output is

```
> output
   group score
1      1    30
2      1    10
3      1    22
8      4    35
9      4     2
10     4    60
```